# I killed a krampus

Tags: the-secret-world

I killed a krampusnacht several times whilst wondering around the savage coast, most recently I noticed that he drops "dead yew branch" when i mouse over the item in my bag it says, "A dead branch of the yew sings a syllable of her true name. The root sinks into grave soil, tickling her face." what does this mean? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used in order to summon Hel, a special boss, in Niflheim. More specifically, it is one of 8 items that must be used. The details of this are outlined on [this page](http://www.tsw-rp.com/mobile/forum/viewthread/m/5359865/id/10000349-krampus-event-faq-spoilers) in the FAQ spoiler section. The "her" in the description refers to Hel.